# Exporting CSV really strange formatted

Tags: java, android, opencsv

What am i doing? I am exporting my sqlite database into a csv -- atleast i *try to*

I've done this both manually and with ["OpenCSV"](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

With both methods I get very strange results. They just seem not well formatted. Neither the columns (which are usually seperated by ',' ? ) nor special characters (which are said to be handled within opencsv) look like they should. code:

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file),'\n',',');

        String[] items = new String[11];
        c.moveToFirst();

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){


        items[0] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
        items[1] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_QRCODE));
        items[2] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_NAME));
        items[3] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_AMOUNT));
        items[4] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_UNIT));
        items[5] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_PPU));
        items[6] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_TOTAL));
        items[7] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_COMMENT));
        items[8] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.ITEM_SHOPPING));
        items[9] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.CREATED_DATE));
        items[10] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DepotTableMetaData.MODIFIED_DATE));

        c.moveToNext();
        writer.writeNext(items);

        }

        writer.close();
```

and it all gives this as a result:

[image]

I've also done it through FileWriter and StringBuffer but it seems to give exactly the same results...I'd love if you could help me ;)

I have looked through stackoverflow but couldn't find any matching question ;/

edit: yes i know that I use the "old, deprecated" cursor, but that's not the question here. Thanks.

edit2: **SOLVED** !
you have to assign some common encoding !

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destination+"/output.csv"),"UTF-8"));
```

did the job perfectly!

Comment: You're using a csv library but appending the commas yourself...

Comment: let me update the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an OpenCSV Writer, which takes a row of the CSV file as an array of Strings, and generates the separators between columns and rows automatically, but instead of letting OpenCSV do it for you, you do it explicitely by appending all the values of a row in a single String. So obviously, OpenCSV takes your unique value and considers it contains a single column, where commas and newlines must be encoded.

You should call `writer.writeNext()` with an array of Strings, each String in the array being a single cell from the table. The writer will generate the commas and the newlines for you.

Comment: sounds good, but didn't work. I got this as result <a href="http://i.imgur.com/GRP1L.png">imgur link2</a> ..
the lines are being made properly anyway, but the columns not. and there is still the issue with the special characters... :/

Comment: CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destination+"/output.csv"),"UTF-8"));
did the job... still I'll give you the accept, as you've given me a tipp too!